# How to perform a self-referential correlated subquery with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have historically avoided ORMs in favor of hand-written SQL. However, I find myself now trying to use SQLAlchemy for a project, because it seemed to make sense for this project. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to port some of the slightly more complex SQL to SQLAlchemy.

I have something of a linked-list implemented as follows:

```py
class TransactionModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'transactionlog'
    chain = Column(String(36), primary_key = True)
    id = Column(String(36), primary_key = True)
    overwrite_id = Column(String(36))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    user = relationship(UserModel, foreign_keys=[user_id])

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['chain', 'overwrite_id'],
            ['transactionlog.chain', 'transactionlog.id']
        ),
    )
```

Most things seem pretty straightforward:

```py
# Prev Item in list
TransactionModel.query.filter((TransactionModel.chain == current.chain) & (TransactionModel.id == current.overwrite_id)).one()
# Next item in list
TransactionModel.query.filter((TransactionModel.chain == current.chain) & (TransactionModel.overwrite_id == current.id)).one()
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get the last item in the list. If I were writing SQL by hand, I would do this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM transactionlog AS t
WHERE chain = "somevalue"
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM transactionlog AS other
    WHERE other.chain = t.chain
    AND other.overwrite_id = t.id
)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to translate this into SQLAlchemy though. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to write this in SQLAlchemy, I'd use [`sqlalchemy.exists()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html?highlight=exists#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists) and [`sqlalchemy.orm.aliased`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased). The latter allows you to have essentially a named copy of the model, so you can distinguish between the same table:

```py
from sqlalchemy import exists
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

other = aliased(TransactionModel)

TransactionModel.query.filter(
    TransactionModel.chain == "somevalue",
    ~exists().where(
        (other.overwrite_id == TransactionModel.id) &
        (other.chain == TransactionModel.chain)
    )
)
```

or equivalently (using `and_` instead of `&`)

```py
from sqlalchemy import and_, exists
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

other = aliased(TransactionModel)

TransactionModel.query.filter(
    TransactionModel.chain == "somevalue",
    ~exists().where(and_(
        other.overwrite_id == TransactionModel.id,
        other.chain == TransactionModel.chain
    ))
)
```

Comment: I had to replace the `other.c` portion with simply `other`. After that, it worked great. I also like that it looks pretty close to what I would have written in plain SQL. Thanks!